# Constantly accelerated motion in a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

What are the conditions for an object to move in a PLANE with CONSTANT acceleration? Like, should it move in a straight direction with constant acceleration because if it changes its direction, then the direction of velocity changes and hence, the direction of acceleration also changes and then it doesn't remains constant and then we can't call the motion of the body constantly accelerated motion in a plane.

Comment: I think you must change your title by : *"Plane motion with constant acceleration vector"*.

Comment: @Frobenius , do you know the answer? If yes, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Any motion under constant acceleration is contained in a plane. To see that let's set up the problem in a convenient way and calculate the relevant quantities.For constant acceleration we have:

$$\vec a(t)= \vec a_0 \implies \vec v(t)= \vec v_0 + \vec a_0*t$$

Choosing any two arbitrary points in the trajectory, $t= \tau_1$ and $t=\tau_2$:

$$\vec v(\tau_1)= \vec v_0 + \vec a_0*\tau_1$$
$$\vec v(\tau_2)= \vec v_0 + \vec a_0*\tau_2$$

Construct a vector that is perpendicular to both:

$$\vec v(\tau_1) \times \vec v(\tau_2)= (\vec a_0 \times \vec v_0)*(\tau_1-\tau_2)$$

Now check if this vector is also perpendicular to the rest of the trajectory:

$$\vec v(t) \cdot (\vec a_0 \times \vec v_0)*(\tau_1-\tau_2)=(\tau_1-\tau_2)*[\vec v_0 \cdot (\vec a_0 \times \vec v_0)+t*\vec a_0 \cdot (\vec a_0 \times \vec v_0)]$$

Both triple products vanish because they have repeated vectors. The velocity vector is always tangent to the trajectory, and the constant vector ($\vec a_0 \times \vec v_0$) is perpendicular to the velocity vector. We just found a constant vector that is perpendicular to the whole trajectory, then the trajectory lies on a  plane.

Comment: You answer the question *"What are the conditions for an object to move in a PLANE with CONSTANT acceleration?"* implicitly : *"Any motion under constant acceleration is contained in a plane."* Explicitly : There is not any condition for this to be valid. It is valid automatically.

Comment: No, not every motion with constant acceleration is contained in a plane. Rectilinear motion is an example.

Comment: @Suraj Chauhan That is not correct. A line is surely contained in a plane. The question did not ask if there is a unique plane for any given constant $\vec a$. It asked if there exists a plane where the motion is contained for any given constant acceleration $\vec a$, and that is true even for rectilinear motion, the difference is that there will be an infinite number of planes that contain the motion in that case, but you can surely choose a plane such that the trajectory is contained in it

Comment: But if you want the motion to be contained in a unique plane,it is really straightforward. From the answer I gave, it is easy to see that all you need is for $\vec a$ and $\vec v_0$ to be non zero and not in the same direction, then the motion won’t be rectilinear, so you’ll have a unique plane where the trajectory is contained.